# JQuery - Как создать переменную только для context?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот, например, есть такой код:

```
var width = $('.additional', context).outerWidth();
```

Проблема в том, что она будет равна `outerWidth()` последнего `context` (у меня что-то типа цикла с ними). А как создать для каждого `context` свою переменную?

Comment: Советую тебе развернуть вопрос,  написать более подробно. С минимальным самодостаточным примером.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вы имели ввиду что-то такое. Здесь будет перебор всех `.additional` в рамках `context` и получение их параметров. Точно так же как в выборке по полному DOM.

```js
$('.additional', context).each(function(){
  var width = $(this).outerWidth();
  //и делаем что-нибудь с каждым width
});
```